# css image max-width not working with Firefox / IE

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer, firefox, responsive-design

Here's a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NrCGb/594/).

HTML :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<div data-role="page" >
    <div id="contentwrap">
        <div id="content" data-role="content">
             <img width="300" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f1/Ski_trail_rating_symbol_red_circle.png" />

          asdad asd asd asd   sadadada ad sad asd asd asd asd sadasdaad adsa dasd sa
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
}

#contentwrap {
display: table;
height: 100%;
max-width: 500px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
}

#contentwrap img {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
display:block;
margin-bottom: 10px;

max-width:100%;
}

#content {
height: 100%;
display: table-cell;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

As you can see if you test it, the "max-width: 100%" attribute only works on Google Chrome. With Firefox and IE, the image width stay the same... With Chrome, the image adapt to the window... :

[image]

How can I fix it ? (at least with IE11)

I found other posts with the same problem but none gave a good solution...

Comment: have you tried removing the width attribute of the image?

Comment: display:table;max-width:500px; gives 2 reasons why max-width:100%; on child cannot be applied :( , try max-width:500px on img

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way of achieving the desired layout.

I left out some of the jQuery Mobile classes and just used native CSS/CSS3.

For this **HTML**:

```
<div id="contentwrap">
    <div id="content">
        <img width="300" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f1/Ski_trail_rating_symbol_red_circle.png" />
        asdad asd asd asd sadadada ad sad asd asd asd asd sadasdaad adsa dasd sa
    </div>
</div>
```

modify your **CSS** as follows:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
#contentwrap {
    background-color: beige;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
}
#content {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
#content img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
}
```

I applied CSS tables to `#contentwrap` and `#content` similarly to your original CSS, that way you get the vertical alignment in the middle as required.

You hard coded the image width to 300px by setting the `width` value in the `img` tag.

To get the image to scale with the width of `#content` as it narrows in width, set the `width: 100%` that way the image will fill the width of `#content`, and to prevent the image from getting too wide, set a `max-width` value as needed, 300px in my exammple.

You may run into conflicts with CSS rules in jQuery Mobile, but perhaps someone else can help with any issues is they arise (not my area of expertise).

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/ZMLDD/

**Note:** If you set the `max-width` value for the image, then you may not need to set the `width` attribute in the `img` tag.

I checked this in the latest versions of Firefox, Chrome, IE and Opera and this solution appears to work.

Answer (score 5):

There's actually a really simple solution to this -- you need to set the `table-layout` property to `fixed` on the element that is set to `display: table`.

```css
#contentwrap {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Always remember, max-width does not inherit from other parent
>   elements. As the width of 300px has been defined with a max-width of
>   100%, the initial width value will always override the max-width value
>   of 100%

So instead use `min-width: 300px` and `max-width: 100%` which will make it to work in all the browsers

Answer (score 0):

Responsive images for Firefox, IE, Chrome. Simple solution that works in Firefox

```
<div class="article"><img></div>

.article {background: transparent 0% 0% / 100% auto;}
.article img {max-width: 100%;}
```